# How to access "jasmine" variable

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to mock the router. But more importantly I'm trying to access `jasmine` in my code. I'm running Karma v 6.3.20 and Jasmine 3.8. In my code, I need to use a Jasmine Spy.

I want to do something like `jasmine.createSpy(...);` but `jasmine` is undefined. How do I define the `jasmine` variable everyone references.

Example: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#routing-component

```
const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigateByUrl']);
const heroServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HeroService', ['getHeroes']);

TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: HeroService, useValue: heroServiceSpy}, {provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy}
      ]
    })
```

I've tried to `npm install --save-dev jasmine` and then `import jasmine from 'jasmine'` but that doesn't even import. I get an error saying "Module jasmine can only be default-imported using the ‘allowSyntheticDefaultImports’ flag"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the packages `@types/jasmine` and `jasmine` installed and in `tsconfig.spec.json`, `jasmine` is specified in the `types` array under `compilerOptions`.

```
"types": ["jasmine", "node"]
```

Something else you can do is to generate an empty Angular project with the CLI and then go to the unit test file and see `jasmine` being available and try to copy its config. Files that should be looked are `package.json`, `angular.json`, `tsconfig.json`, `test.ts`, and `tsconfig.spec.json`.